# Acer Aspire WiFi connection is intermittent

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire 5250, Windows 7. After many trials the WiFi is at most intermittent.

What should I do to resolve this problem? Should I purchase an external router?

Comment: Read the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions) about what kind of questions you can ask here.

Comment: You shouldn't buy an external router, that won't help. Install the latest driver, if possible. Then report back.

Comment: By External router, do you mean external USB WIFI device or WIFI card for the Acer?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a spare USB WiFi adapter to check if the WiFi connection works as expected?

If not, try removing/uninstalling your WiFi drivers and reinstalling the latest from [here](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=3677). Make sure you download the correct driver according to your wireless chipset vendor.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine purchased this same laptop and had issues with getting connections at more than 15 feet from the access point.  Updated the drivers to the latest version and saw no improvement.  Opened the access panel on the bottom of the machine and found that this unit only had one wireless antenna - and it was connected to the wrong port.  In most devices you will find both a black and a white antenna lead which are tuned differently.  In this case ther ewas just a black lead but it was attached to the white jack.  Attached the antenna lead to the proper connector and 23 wireless networks showed up that I know covered at least 200 feet from the machine.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do always is too see if there's a newer driver for your wireless card. Sometimes the one that is shipped with the machine isn't up to date. Other things that you can try is update your router firmware there might be sometimes bugs and patches provided by the manufacture. If neither one still helps, see if your are close a cordless phone they share the same frequency as the routers depending on how new your router is that might be intefering with it as well.

Good Luck